# Unexpected String concat behaviour

Tags: java, string, solaris, string-concatenation

I'm in trouble with some simple Java code :

```
// the env var is set 
public final String METACHEK_pref = System.getenv().get("MCHK_DIR"); 
// the env var should be :
public String tempMP = "/disk3/METACHECK/Metacheck/metachek";

System.out.println("#1:"+METACHEK_pref+File.separator+"metachek"); 
System.out.println("#2:"+tempMP+File.separator+"metachek");
```

which prints:

```
#1:/metachekTACHECK/Metacheck/metachek
#2:/disk3/METACHECK/Metacheck/metachek/metachek
```

I've tried that code in different OS and just one solaris have this problem. And, of course, the code has to work on this specific server.

I've no idea to where to check if it's some strange parameters to set in an hidden conf file.

Anyone has an idea what's going on? Why the concat has evolved to an insert command?

EDIT:

I've created another jar with this code:

```
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String METACHEK_pref = new String(System.getenv().get("MCHK_DIR").toString());
        String tempMP = "/disk3/METACHECK/Metacheck/metachek";

        System.out.println("#1:"+METACHEK_pref); 
        System.out.println("#2:"+METACHEK_pref+File.separator+"metachek");
        System.out.println("#3:"+tempMP+File.separator+"metachek");



    }

}
```

and this is the output:

> ```
> #1:/disk3/METACHECK/Metacheck/metachek
>  /metachek/METACHECK/Metacheck/metachek
> #3:/disk3/METACHECK/Metacheck/metachek/metachek
> ```

See how the #2 disappear?

Comment: Are you sure MCHK_DIR variable is really set to what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it is as an system env var. As you can see in the first sysout, the path is well get but the concat part is the bad spot

Comment: @user1808484 first of all print METACHEK_pref alone, please

Comment: you can also print them all: for(Entry<String, String> entry: System.getenv()) { System.out.println(entry.getKey()); System.out.println(entry.getValue()); }

Comment: the METACHEK_pref is all right. if I print METACHEK_pref it says /disk3/METACHECK/Metacheck/metachek . If I print any concatenation of METACHEK_pref plus anything , the first characters of METACHEK_pref are replaced . I've tried +, .concat() , using StringBuilder but none of these do the job ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that the `MCHK_DIR` environment variable ends in a CR character (carriage return, better known as the-first-part-of-CRLF).

This explains pretty exactly what you experience: the visible part of `MCHK_DIR` is printed and the cursor is placed at the beginning of the line. Then the thing you appended is printed (overwriting the start of the visible `MCHK_DIR` text).

*How* this occurs is somewhat of a mystery to me, as most ways to set an environment variable don't make it easy to append a whitespace character (such as CR).

To check if this is indeed the case, iterate over the characters of your variable and print their values:

```
for (char c : METACHEK_pref.toCharArray()) {
  System.out.println("<" + c + ">: " + (int) c);
}
```

Comment: Here come the last char of the METACHEK_pref :
>: 13
So, you're right ! THANKS YOU !

Answer (score 1):

i guess, @Joachim Sauer is correct.
If it is the case,

```
   String METACHEK_pref = System.getenv("MCHK_DIR").trim();
```

should do the tirck.